# Fastest way to convert 3D coordinates from string to float in a numpy array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy, type-conversion

I have 3D coordinates (strings) in a list that I would like to convert to arrays of floats.

```
# current list
iPoints = ['-50.0651394154927,-5.3133315588409,0', '-48.7824404616692,3.1894817418136,0', '-46.2317402190515,11.3986203175639,0']

# ideal output
array([[-50.0651394154927,-5.3133315588409,0], [-48.7824404616692,3.1894817418136,0], [-46.2317402190515,11.3986203175639,0]])
```

A naive implementation:

```
iPoints = np.array([[float(c) for c in v.split(',')] for v in iPoints])
```

What would be the fastest way to convert this list of strings to a numpy array of arrays ?

Comment: Forget speed for now.  Start with list and string operations.

Comment: @hpaulj Question has been edited. Speed is an issue when converting large amounts of coordinates.

Comment: Show us how you'd do it without a focus on speed, and then we can talk about improving it.

Comment: @hpaulj Sure, question edited.

Comment: A good start.  `np.array([v.split(',') ....], dtype=float)` can convert the strings to floats, so you don't need the inner comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

The original solution is surprisingly fast but it can be done faster.
You can join the strings to one large buffer and process it with one call to `np.fromstring`.

Try following code:

```
# put everthing to a buffer as a large 1D-array separated with commas
buf = ','.join(iPoints)
# parse the buffer
iPoints = np.fromstring(buf, sep=',', dtype=float, count=3*len(iPoints))
# make it 3d again
iPoints = iPoints.reshape(-1,3)
```

I've made some benchmark.

```
iPoints=['-50.0651394154927,-5.3133315588409,0', '-48.7824404616692,3.1894817418136,0', '-46.2317402190515,11.3986203175639,0']
# lets make it a little large
iMorePoints = iPoints * 10000

method1 = lambda: np.array([[float(c) for c in v.split(',')] for v in iMorePoints])
method2 = lambda: np.fromstring(','.join(iMorePoints), sep=',', dtype=float, count=3*len(iMorePoints)).reshape(-1,3)
```

Results on my machine are:

```
>>> timeit(method1, number=100)
3.6391940720000093
>>> timeit(method2, number=100)
1.0472392480000963
```

So the proposed solution is 3.5 times faster. The small disadvantage is that one must know in advance that vectors are 3-dimensional. But it can be checked with call `iPoints[0].count(',')+1`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the benchmark. I have timed the 3 different solutions (mine, hpaulj's and yours) and get different timings. Overall the results are quite similar on my side.